# Virtualization and Deployments / Upgrades

Tags: vmware, virtualization, release-management, hyper-v

I'm hoping someone may be able to help point me in the right direction.

We have an application suite that currently spans 4 virtual machines on an installation. We support both VMWare and HyperV.

Knowing each developer has there own setup, each time a new build is completed (containing bug fixes and features), each developer is required to upgrade there systems. This takes a considerable amount of time, downloading of the new builds, executing the builds, testing to ensure your still operational and then take a snapshot of the systems.

Each system has configuration files that are not portable between images; these contain server information, IP addresses etc.

Is there any way, the upgrade could be done once and deployed to each of the developer setup's (without overwriting the existing image as the image would have all the configuration information) ?

Comment: VMware Compliance Checker does some of the work

Answer (score 4):

Let me have a try to see whether I get your point. From what I feel, it looks like what you want is a solution of VM cycle management, from very begingning OS Installation to Configuration managemnt (include software patch installation).
If your guest OS is Linux， there is some mainstream open source solution for you.

1. OS installtion, recommand cobbler(http://cobbler.github.com/), with it you can specify IP address, hostname as you wish for new OS installtion, cobbler support both VM and pysical machine.
2. Configuration Management, recommand puppet(https://puppetlabs.com/), software update rules can be customize as you wish, puppet is very power to use.

If the guest OS is non-linux system, like windows, you'd better look for some similiar solution in windows world. All in all, everything I talked is under one computer science topic, called CM, Configuration management, you can find its defination from wiki.

Hope above things helpful for you.